# How to get the network / usb interfaces in qemu

Tags: networking, usb, qemu

I am trying to run Jessy minimal in Qemu 2.9.0 This is the command

```
qemu-system-arm -M raspi2 -kernel rasp-boot/kernel7.img \
-sd 2017-07-05-raspbian-jessie-lite.img \
-append "rw earlyprintk loglevel=8 console=ttyAMA0,115200 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2" \
-dtb rasp-boot/bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb -serial stdio
```

The `rasp-boot` directory (on my PC) contains all the files from the first partition of the SDCARD image.

Note that `-M raspi3` is not an option, but if I boot with the version 2 device table it does not recognize the mmcblk device.

Isn't the device table supposed to tell qemu what devices are included? I am getting the following results

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.10.0/24
SIOCSIFADDR: No such device
eth0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
SIOCSIFNETMASK: No such device
```

No luck with USB either

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ lsusb
unable to initialize libusb: -99
```

Are these things expected to work in the emulator?

Comment: FWIW I did my simulation on Debian in VirtualBox instead.